# FFMPEG RTSP Server using muxing doc example

Tags: c, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtsp

I am trying to develop RTSP server using FFMPEG. For that I slightly modified muxing file located at `doc/example/` folder inside FFMPEG repository.

Giving my source code of RTSP server example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <libavutil/avassert.h>
#include <libavutil/channel_layout.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavutil/mathematics.h>
#include <libavutil/timestamp.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <libswresample/swresample.h>

#define STREAM_DURATION   10.0
#define STREAM_FRAME_RATE 25 /* 25 images/s */
#define STREAM_PIX_FMT    AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P /* default pix_fmt */

#define SCALE_FLAGS SWS_BICUBIC

// a wrapper around a single output AVStream
typedef struct OutputStream {
    AVStream *st;
    AVCodecContext *enc;

    /* pts of the next frame that will be generated */
    int64_t next_pts;
    int samples_count;

    AVFrame *frame;
    AVFrame *tmp_frame;

    float t, tincr, tincr2;

    struct SwsContext *sws_ctx;
    struct SwrContext *swr_ctx;
} OutputStream;

static void log_packet(const AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx, const AVPacket *pkt)
{
    AVRational *time_base = &fmt_ctx->streams[pkt->stream_index]->time_base;

    printf("pts:%s pts_time:%s dts:%s dts_time:%s duration:%s duration_time:%s stream_index:%d\n",
           av_ts2str(pkt->pts), av_ts2timestr(pkt->pts, time_base),
           av_ts2str(pkt->dts), av_ts2timestr(pkt->dts, time_base),
           av_ts2str(pkt->duration), av_ts2timestr(pkt->duration, time_base),
           pkt->stream_index);
}

static int write_frame(AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx, const AVRational *time_base, AVStream *st, AVPacket *pkt)
{
    /* rescale output packet timestamp values from codec to stream timebase */
    av_packet_rescale_ts(pkt, *time_base, st->time_base);
    pkt->stream_index = st->index;

    /* Write the compressed frame to the media file. */
    log_packet(fmt_ctx, pkt);
    return av_interleaved_write_frame(fmt_ctx, pkt);
}

/* Add an output stream. */
static void add_stream(OutputStream *ost, AVFormatContext *oc,
                       AVCodec **codec,
                       enum AVCodecID codec_id)
{
    AVCodecContext *c;
    int i;

    /* find the encoder */
    *codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codec_id);
    if (!(*codec)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find encoder for '%s'\n",
                avcodec_get_name(codec_id));
        exit(1);
    }

    ost->st = avformat_new_stream(oc, NULL);
    if (!ost->st) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate stream\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    ost->st->id = oc->nb_streams-1;
    c = avcodec_alloc_context3(*codec);
    if (!c) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not alloc an encoding context\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    ost->enc = c;

    switch ((*codec)->type) {
    case AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO:
        c->sample_fmt  = (*codec)->sample_fmts ?
            (*codec)->sample_fmts[0] : AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP;
        c->bit_rate    = 64000;
        c->sample_rate = 44100;
        if ((*codec)->supported_samplerates) {
            c->sample_rate = (*codec)->supported_samplerates[0];
            for (i = 0; (*codec)->supported_samplerates[i]; i++) {
                if ((*codec)->supported_samplerates[i] == 44100)
                    c->sample_rate = 44100;
            }
        }
        c->channels        = av_get_channel_layout_nb_channels(c->channel_layout);
        c->channel_layout = AV_CH_LAYOUT_STEREO;
        if ((*codec)->channel_layouts) {
            c->channel_layout = (*codec)->channel_layouts[0];
            for (i = 0; (*codec)->channel_layouts[i]; i++) {
                if ((*codec)->channel_layouts[i] == AV_CH_LAYOUT_STEREO)
                    c->channel_layout = AV_CH_LAYOUT_STEREO;
            }
        }
        c->channels        = av_get_channel_layout_nb_channels(c->channel_layout);
        ost->st->time_base = (AVRational){ 1, c->sample_rate };
        break;

    case AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO:
        c->codec_id = codec_id;

        c->bit_rate = 400000;
        /* Resolution must be a multiple of two. */
        c->width    = 352;
        c->height   = 288;
        /* timebase: This is the fundamental unit of time (in seconds) in terms
         * of which frame timestamps are represented. For fixed-fps content,
         * timebase should be 1/framerate and timestamp increments should be
         * identical to 1. */
        ost->st->time_base = (AVRational){ 1, STREAM_FRAME_RATE };
        c->time_base       = ost->st->time_base;

        c->gop_size      = 12; /* emit one intra frame every twelve frames at most */
        c->pix_fmt       = STREAM_PIX_FMT;
        if (c->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO) {
            /* just for testing, we also add B-frames */
            c->max_b_frames = 2;
        }
        if (c->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO) {
            /* Needed to avoid using macroblocks in which some coeffs overflow.
             * This does not happen with normal video, it just happens here as
             * the motion of the chroma plane does not match the luma plane. */
            c->mb_decision = 2;
        }
   break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    /* Some formats want stream headers to be separate. */
    if (oc->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
        c->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
}

/**************************************************************/
/* audio output */

static AVFrame *alloc_audio_frame(enum AVSampleFormat sample_fmt,
                                  uint64_t channel_layout,
                                  int sample_rate, int nb_samples)
{
    AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();
    int ret;

    if (!frame) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating an audio frame\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    frame->format = sample_fmt;
    frame->channel_layout = channel_layout;
    frame->sample_rate = sample_rate;
    frame->nb_samples = nb_samples;

    if (nb_samples) {
        ret = av_frame_get_buffer(frame, 0);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating an audio buffer\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    return frame;
}

static void open_audio(AVFormatContext *oc, AVCodec *codec, OutputStream *ost, AVDictionary *opt_arg)
{
    AVCodecContext *c;
    int nb_samples;
    int ret;
   AVDictionary *opt = NULL;

    c = ost->enc;

    /* open it */
    av_dict_copy(&opt, opt_arg, 0);
    ret = avcodec_open2(c, codec, &opt);
    av_dict_free(&opt);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open audio codec: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
        exit(1);
    }

    /* init signal generator */
    ost->t     = 0;
    ost->tincr = 2 * M_PI * 110.0 / c->sample_rate;
    /* increment frequency by 110 Hz per second */
    ost->tincr2 = 2 * M_PI * 110.0 / c->sample_rate / c->sample_rate;

    if (c->codec->capabilities & AV_CODEC_CAP_VARIABLE_FRAME_SIZE)
        nb_samples = 10000;
    else
        nb_samples = c->frame_size;

    ost->frame     = alloc_audio_frame(c->sample_fmt, c->channel_layout,
                                       c->sample_rate, nb_samples);
    ost->tmp_frame = alloc_audio_frame(AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16, c->channel_layout,
                                       c->sample_rate, nb_samples);

    /* copy the stream parameters to the muxer */
    ret = avcodec_parameters_from_context(ost->st->codecpar, c);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not copy the stream parameters\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* create resampler context */
        ost->swr_ctx = swr_alloc();
        if (!ost->swr_ctx) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate resampler context\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        /* set options */
        av_opt_set_int       (ost->swr_ctx, "in_channel_count",   c->channels,       0);
        av_opt_set_int       (ost->swr_ctx, "in_sample_rate",     c->sample_rate,    0);
        av_opt_set_sample_fmt(ost->swr_ctx, "in_sample_fmt",      AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16, 0);
        av_opt_set_int       (ost->swr_ctx, "out_channel_count",  c->channels,       0);
        av_opt_set_int       (ost->swr_ctx, "out_sample_rate",    c->sample_rate,    0);
        av_opt_set_sample_fmt(ost->swr_ctx, "out_sample_fmt",     c->sample_fmt,     0);

        /* initialize the resampling context */
        if ((ret = swr_init(ost->swr_ctx)) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize the resampling context\n");
            exit(1);
        }
}

/* Prepare a 16 bit dummy audio frame of 'frame_size' samples and
 * 'nb_channels' channels. */
static AVFrame *get_audio_frame(OutputStream *ost)
{
    AVFrame *frame = ost->tmp_frame;
    int j, i, v;
    int16_t *q = (int16_t*)frame->data[0];

    /* check if we want to generate more frames */
    if (av_compare_ts(ost->next_pts, ost->enc->time_base,
                      STREAM_DURATION, (AVRational){ 1, 1 }) >= 0)
        return NULL;

    for (j = 0; j <frame->nb_samples; j++) {
        v = (int)(sin(ost->t) * 10000);
        for (i = 0; i < ost->enc->channels; i++)
            *q++ = v;
        ost->t     += ost->tincr;
        ost->tincr += ost->tincr2;
    }

    frame->pts = ost->next_pts;
    ost->next_pts  += frame->nb_samples;

    return frame;
}

/*
 * encode one audio frame and send it to the muxer
 * return 1 when encoding is finished, 0 otherwise
 */
static int write_audio_frame(AVFormatContext *oc, OutputStream *ost)
{
    AVCodecContext *c;
    AVPacket pkt = { 0 }; // data and size must be 0;
    AVFrame *frame;
    int ret;
    int got_packet;
    int dst_nb_samples;

    av_init_packet(&pkt);
    c = ost->enc;

    frame = get_audio_frame(ost);

    if (frame) {
        /* convert samples from native format to destination codec format, using the resampler */
            /* compute destination number of samples */
            dst_nb_samples = av_rescale_rnd(swr_get_delay(ost->swr_ctx, c->sample_rate) + frame->nb_samples,
                                            c->sample_rate, c->sample_rate, AV_ROUND_UP);
            av_assert0(dst_nb_samples == frame->nb_samples);

        /* when we pass a frame to the encoder, it may keep a reference to it
         * internally;
        * make sure we do not overwrite it here
         */
        ret = av_frame_make_writable(ost->frame);
        if (ret < 0)
            exit(1);

        /* convert to destination format */
        ret = swr_convert(ost->swr_ctx,
                          ost->frame->data, dst_nb_samples,
                          (const uint8_t **)frame->data, frame->nb_samples);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error while converting\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        frame = ost->frame;

        frame->pts = av_rescale_q(ost->samples_count, (AVRational){1, c->sample_rate}, c->time_base);
        ost->samples_count += dst_nb_samples;
    }

    ret = avcodec_encode_audio2(c, &pkt, frame, &got_packet);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding audio frame: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
        exit(1);
    }

    if (got_packet) {
        ret = write_frame(oc, &c->time_base, ost->st, &pkt);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error while writing audio frame: %s\n",
                    av_err2str(ret));
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    return (frame || got_packet) ? 0 : 1;
}

/**************************************************************/
/* video output */

static AVFrame *alloc_picture(enum AVPixelFormat pix_fmt, int width, int height)
{
    AVFrame *picture;
    int ret;

    picture = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!picture)
        return NULL;

    picture->format = pix_fmt;
    picture->width  = width;
    picture->height = height;

    /* allocate the buffers for the frame data */
    ret = av_frame_get_buffer(picture, 32);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate frame data.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return picture;
}

static void open_video(AVFormatContext *oc, AVCodec *codec, OutputStream *ost, AVDictionary *opt_arg)
{
    int ret;
    AVCodecContext *c = ost->enc;
    AVDictionary *opt = NULL;

    av_dict_copy(&opt, opt_arg, 0);

    /* open the codec */
    ret = avcodec_open2(c, codec, &opt);
    av_dict_free(&opt);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open video codec: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
        exit(1);
    }

    /* allocate and init a re-usable frame */
    ost->frame = alloc_picture(c->pix_fmt, c->width, c->height);
    if (!ost->frame) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video frame\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* If the output format is not YUV420P, then a temporary YUV420P
     * picture is needed too. It is then converted to the required
     * output format. */
    ost->tmp_frame = NULL;
    if (c->pix_fmt != AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P) {
        ost->tmp_frame = alloc_picture(AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, c->width, c->height);
        if (!ost->tmp_frame) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate temporary picture\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    /* copy the stream parameters to the muxer */
    ret = avcodec_parameters_from_context(ost->st->codecpar, c);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not copy the stream parameters\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

/* Prepare a dummy image. */
static void fill_yuv_image(AVFrame *pict, int frame_index,
                           int width, int height)
{
    int x, y, i;

    i = frame_index;

    /* Y */
    for (y = 0; y < height; y++)
        for (x = 0; x < width; x++)
            pict->data[0][y * pict->linesize[0] + x] = x + y + i * 3;

    /* Cb and Cr */
    for (y = 0; y < height / 2; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < width / 2; x++) {
            pict->data[1][y * pict->linesize[1] + x] = 128 + y + i * 2;
            pict->data[2][y * pict->linesize[2] + x] = 64 + x + i * 5;
        }
    }
}

static AVFrame *get_video_frame(OutputStream *ost)
{
    AVCodecContext *c = ost->enc;

    /* check if we want to generate more frames */
    if (av_compare_ts(ost->next_pts, c->time_base,
                      STREAM_DURATION, (AVRational){ 1, 1 }) >= 0)
        return NULL;

    /* when we pass a frame to the encoder, it may keep a reference to it
     * internally; make sure we do not overwrite it here */
    if (av_frame_make_writable(ost->frame) < 0)
        exit(1);

    if (c->pix_fmt != AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P) {
        /* as we only generate a YUV420P picture, we must convert it
         * to the codec pixel format if needed */
        if (!ost->sws_ctx) {
            ost->sws_ctx = sws_getContext(c->width, c->height,
                                          AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
                                          c->width, c->height,
                                          c->pix_fmt,
                                          SCALE_FLAGS, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            if (!ost->sws_ctx) {
                fprintf(stderr,
                        "Could not initialize the conversion context\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        fill_yuv_image(ost->tmp_frame, ost->next_pts, c->width, c->height);
        sws_scale(ost->sws_ctx,
                  (const uint8_t * const *)ost->tmp_frame->data, ost->tmp_frame->linesize,
                  0, c->height, ost->frame->data, ost->frame->linesize);
    } else {
        fill_yuv_image(ost->frame, ost->next_pts, c->width, c->height);
    }

    ost->frame->pts = ost->next_pts++;

    return ost->frame;
}

/*
 * encode one video frame and send it to the muxer
 * return 1 when encoding is finished, 0 otherwise
 */
static int write_video_frame(AVFormatContext *oc, OutputStream *ost)
{
    int ret;
    AVCodecContext *c;
    AVFrame *frame;
    int got_packet = 0;
    AVPacket pkt = { 0 };

    c = ost->enc;

    frame = get_video_frame(ost);

    av_init_packet(&pkt);

    /* encode the image */
    ret = avcodec_encode_video2(c, &pkt, frame, &got_packet);
    if (ret < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding video frame: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
        exit(1);
    }

    if (got_packet) {
        ret = write_frame(oc, &c->time_base, ost->st, &pkt);
    } else {
        ret = 0;
    }

    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while writing video frame: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
        exit(1);
    }

    return (frame || got_packet) ? 0 : 1;
}

static void close_stream(AVFormatContext *oc, OutputStream *ost)
{
    avcodec_free_context(&ost->enc);
    av_frame_free(&ost->frame);
    av_frame_free(&ost->tmp_frame);
    sws_freeContext(ost->sws_ctx);
    swr_free(&ost->swr_ctx);
}

/**************************************************************/
/* media file output */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    OutputStream video_st = { 0 }, audio_st = { 0 };
    const char *filename;
    AVOutputFormat *fmt;
    AVFormatContext *oc;
    AVCodec *audio_codec, *video_codec;
    int ret;
    int have_video = 0, have_audio = 0;
    int encode_video = 0, encode_audio = 0;
    AVDictionary *opt = NULL;
    int i;

    /* Initialize libavcodec, and register all codecs and formats. */
    av_register_all();
    avformat_network_init();
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("usage: %s output_file\n"
               "API example program to output a media file with libavformat.\n"
               "This program generates a synthetic audio and video stream, encodes and\n"
               "muxes them into a file named output_file.\n"
               "The output format is automatically guessed according to the file extension.\n"
               "Raw images can also be output by using '%%d' in the filename.\n"
               "\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    filename = argv[1];
    for (i = 2; i+1 < argc; i+=2) {
        if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-flags") || !strcmp(argv[i], "-fflags"))
            av_dict_set(&opt, argv[i]+1, argv[i+1], 0);
    }
   /* allocate the output media context */
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&oc, NULL, "rtsp", filename);
    if (!oc) {
        printf("Could not deduce output format from file extension: using MPEG.\n");
        avformat_alloc_output_context2(&oc, NULL, "mpeg", filename);
    }
    if (!oc)
        return 1;

    fmt = oc->oformat;

    /* Add the audio and video streams using the default format codecs
     * and initialize the codecs. */
    if (fmt->video_codec != AV_CODEC_ID_NONE) {
        add_stream(&video_st, oc, &video_codec, fmt->video_codec);
        have_video = 1;
        encode_video = 1;
    }
    if (fmt->audio_codec != AV_CODEC_ID_NONE) {
        add_stream(&audio_st, oc, &audio_codec, fmt->audio_codec);
        have_audio = 1;
        encode_audio = 1;
    }

    /* Now that all the parameters are set, we can open the audio and
     * video codecs and allocate the necessary encode buffers. */
    if (have_video)
        open_video(oc, video_codec, &video_st, opt);

    if (have_audio)
        open_audio(oc, audio_codec, &audio_st, opt);

    av_dump_format(oc, 0, filename, 1);

    /* open the output file, if needed */
    if (!(fmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        ret = avio_open(&oc->pb, filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open '%s': %s\n", filename,
                    av_err2str(ret));
            return 1;
        }
    }

    /* Write the stream header, if any. */
    ret = avformat_write_header(oc, &opt);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred when opening output file: %s\n",
                av_err2str(ret));
        return 1;
    }

    while (encode_video || encode_audio) {
        /* select the stream to encode */
        if (encode_video &&
           (!encode_audio || av_compare_ts(video_st.next_pts, video_st.enc->time_base,
                                            audio_st.next_pts, audio_st.enc->time_base) <= 0)) {
            encode_video = !write_video_frame(oc, &video_st);
        } else {
            encode_audio = !write_audio_frame(oc, &audio_st);
        }
    }

    /* Write the trailer, if any. The trailer must be written before you
     * close the CodecContexts open when you wrote the header; otherwise
     * av_write_trailer() may try to use memory that was freed on
     * av_codec_close(). */
    av_write_trailer(oc);

    /* Close each codec. */
    if (have_video)
        close_stream(oc, &video_st);
    if (have_audio)
        close_stream(oc, &audio_st);

    if (!(fmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
        /* Close the output file. */
        avio_closep(&oc->pb);

    /* free the stream */
    avformat_free_context(oc);

    return 0;
}
```

After compiling it, I am running binary:

```
$ ./muxing rtsp://127.0.0.1/test
Output #0, rtsp, to 'rtsp://127.0.0.1/test':
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 352x288, q=2-31, 400 kb/s, 25 tbn
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 64 kb/s
[tcp @ 0x2b9d220] Connection to tcp://127.0.0.1:554?timeout=0 failed: Connection refused
Error occurred when opening output file: Connection refused
```

But getting Connection refused error,

Comment: Are you expecting something to be listening for connections on 127.0.0.1:554? This implies you have started some service that binds to port 554 on the local machine. Whatever "muxing" does, it seems to require this service being up, so you should make sure you have actually started such a service on the local host.

Comment: I think it will act as server, so I dont require other service to run on 554 port.

Comment: And in this code I have given data into rtsp output.

Comment: Well, it's not bound to port 554 on this host. You need to solve that first. Since your code doesn't seem to contain any refs to binding TCP/UDP services to any hosts, there must be some other part at play. Check that this service is running. Check that it is not blocked by a local firewall or other permissions related issue.

Comment: Firewall was already disabled and I tried to run binary as root user but not get success.

Comment: I don't think anyone can help you with this highly environmental issue without way more information. What action starts this service? What keeps it running? How do you know it is running? One thing seems for sure: the code you show here does not start a service or listen to this port on any host, unless the libraries it uses does this for you. It's unclear to me, and probably to others, what this code does in the context of some service we don't know about.

Comment: @Harshil, the code you posted does not act as a server. Please search the internet on how to set up e.g. nginx on port 554 as rtsp server, that will lead you to success.

Comment: Thanks Harry, I am looking for example on how to setup rtsp server using ffmpeg, but not find any example.  Do you have any example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this repository for rtsp server using ffserver code:

https://github.com/harshil1991/ffserver.git

Now I can able to integrate this source code in my existing repo.